# SUMIF column in column's row, is the same as another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have two sheets.

#### Income (Sheet1):

```
A          | B      | C
Job number | Amount | Net
1          | 100    | 
2          | 200    | 
3          | 100    | 
4          | 60     |
5          | 100    | 
6          | 100    | 
7          | 100    | 
8          | 100    |
```

And

#### Outcome (Sheet2):

```
A          | B      | C
Job number | Amount | Title
1          | 5      | Stationery
2          | 15     | Printer ink
2          | 10     | et 
2          | 10     |
4          | 20     | 
6          | 30     | 
8          | 10     | 
8          | 10     |
```

How can I write a formula for Sheet1 Column C, to sum values of Sheet2 Column B, where Sheet2 ColumnA is equal to the job number found in the corresponding Sheet1 Column A? That way I can deduct this amount from the income amount, the result being as below:

#### Income (Sheet1)

(Working shown next to desired result)

```
A          | B      | C
Job number | Amount | Net
1          | 100    | 95         (100 - 5)
2          | 200    | 165        (200 - 15 - 10 - 10)
3          | 100    | 100        (100 - nothing)
4          | 60     | 40         (60 - 20)
5          | 100    | 100        (100 - nothing)
6          | 100    | 70         (100 - 30)
7          | 100    | 100        (100 - nothing)
8          | 100    | 80         (100 - 10 - 10)
```

Its nearly this question [Count cells based on a comparison with value in the same row of another column](https://superuser.com/questions/1059549/count-cells-based-on-a-comparison-with-value-in-the-same-row-of-another-column) but not quite... !

Comment: Is using a pivot table from sheet 2's data an option?

Comment: Yes I suppose so – I haven't used them very much before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a tailor-made SUMIF formula, sure, but I love PivotTables. PivotTable skills translate to a much more user-friendly experience without learning (relatively) complicated formula syntax.

Select the data (click inside, hit CTRL-A) of Sheet 2 and go to `Insert > PivotTable`. You probably want to create this on a new sheet. If/when you add more data to the source table, you can find the methods to refresh/expand the pivot table after clicking within it and finding `PivotTable Options` on the ribbon.

From this point you can arrange the pivot table as shown here (the markup I did was just for visual reference):

[image: Pivot Markup]

By doing this you have condensed your data to a single row per job number without changing your source data. From this, you can use a dead-simple VLOOKUP function to do your math:

`=B2-VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet4!A:B,2,FALSE)`

[image: VLOOKUP]

But we have a problem here! We're getting `#N/A` because some of our jobs do not have entries on Sheet 2. The easy fix here is to just account for errors, like so:

`=IFERROR(` ***our formula*** `,` ***original amount***`)`

[image]

If you're just starting out using PivotTables, you're probably more comfortable using basic functions like Vlookup and addition/subtraction, so this method should be more helpful in developing good Excel skills.

Comment: I did the red circle with a Trackball. It looks funny.

Comment: This was great – its much easier to understand than the more concise version

Answer (score 3):

`=SumIf(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9,$A2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$9)` will Sum the values on sheet 2, based on Col A in Sheet 1.

Then, you could just do this in your col. C in Sheet1:

`=$B2-SumIf(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$9,$A2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$9)`

Comment: I provided a much more verbose method of arriving at this same solution, but this is the technically correct answer.

Comment: ["Technically correct" eh?](https://i.imgur.com/gRk1uZm.gif)...:P